# How to clear my autocorrect's word history on S4 mini?

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s-4, auto-correct

I let my younger cousins play on my S4 Mini from time to time, but now I have found that all their words they have used are the first to come up when I use my phone to text. It has gotten quite irrititating. Samsung seems to have very hard to find settings compared to my old sony Ericsson so I cannot find where to get rid of the word history typed onto my phone's keyboard.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Best bet would be to check `System settings > My device > Language and input > Samsung keyboard (gear icon) > Predictive text (make sure this is on / green)`. You might want to check on the `Learn from (word)` items there.

Answer (score 2):

When the suggestion is shown above the keyboard, just tap and hold on that word. It will give you the option to delete it. You **don't** need to clear the complete database just for that!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > My device > Language and input > [default keyboard] settings (gear symbol) > PRESS Predictive text (NOT the slider or tick box!) and it shows a new menu with Auto replacement; Personalised data; clear personalised data etc

S4 mini menu appears to be different to the S4 for some reason

Answer (score 1):

I posted an answer to this where it can be removed from the keyboard when typing and you see the words you want to remove:

[How do I clear keyboard/autocorrect history on the Galaxy s4?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86553/how-do-i-clear-keyboard-autocorrect-history-on-the-galaxy-s4/98912#98912)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto system settings>applications
2. Open the tab of all applications
3. Open the info of the keyboard you use and click on the button 'clear data'
4. Then press back and open the info of 'user dictionary' and press on 'clear data'

All your auto-correct saves have been cleared....Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Above options for delting complete list of learned words.

If you want to delete selected words then  Open your Keyboard and type in the word . when the word appears in the auto correct then touch it continuously and a prompt will appear to delete the word. select ok and the word will be removed from the auto correct list.

Comment: Please add the reference for "above options". The order of how the answers are shown are not the same to all people due to random order for same score :)